# Connection Error while starting SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014

I have installed *SQL Server 2014*, and I did not specify any `password` and `username`, preferred Windows authentication. At the very first time the server connection was successful. But later on this error keeps showing up and the connection fails :

> Server error connection
>   Cannot connect to DESKTOP-4JBE86H
>
> Additional information
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server.The server was not found or was not accessible.( and some additional explanation)
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Have you checked if the SQL Server service had started?

Comment: Thank you so much ! i did now and i fixed the Issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably your SQL services are not working the easiest way to start them is to open cmd with admin rights and type

```
net start mssqlserver
```

And you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

See if the service is standing, and also verify that port 1433 is enabled for network access on the firewall